# how do i use curl command in my python script

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

i am using the following command in terminal and it's working fine,
now i want to get the same result as i get in the terminal.so how i can do this with python script.
actually i need to get the cookies and the curl command give me all cookies values those i needed ,therefore its up best solution for me,so now i want to use it in python script

CURL cmnd:

> curl -i -X PUT https://www.snipes.it

Answer (score 0):

USE requests.get() OR requests.post() TO MAKE A CURL REQUEST

Call requests.get(url) and requests.post(url, data, headers) to make a curl request, or any web request. The url is the url of the specified endpoint, data is the payload to send, and headers should contain any relevant headers for the request.

Comment: i try this but it skip some cookies not give me all cookies

Comment: session = requests.Session()
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
response = session.get('https://snipes.it')# put the name of your site in this to get the cookies  values #
print(session.cookies.get_dict())